# Can't open my animation file

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, export

After animating a specific scene and rending all 100 frames in Cycles via the "Render animation" feature I can play back my animation with the "play rendered animation" button but the file I chose it to be named after can't play. The file exists just the way (I think) it is supposed to exist, with the name showing up and then blender adding the amount of frames the animation ranges from at the end of the file name. When I try to open that .mp4 file I get this message ("Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.").

I really don't want to render that animation again which is why I am asking this: Can I fix the file in some way or access the individually rendered images so that I can manually piece them together?

Comment: do you have any other software to try to play your video? (try quicktime) WMP does not play everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing a proper media player software like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org/), [MPC-BE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe/) or [Potplayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/)

Also for future reference it is always advised to render animations to image sequences, never directly to video file formats

Comment: I use VLC also.

Comment: Wow, I expected the file to just be broken but it did have to do with the player. I downloaded VLC and the playback works perfectly. Thanks!